# How to merge multiple branches automatically

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015, branching-and-merging

I did check other answers, but so far I couldn't found anything similar to my case. All questions are either around the building project, or requires manual merge. I am not an TFS admin or expert, however, here is my question.

We are using TFS 2015 and need to merge multiple brunches on every time check in occurs. Our branches doesn't contain any source code, instead contains some binary files like .exe and text based files like .config or .txt.

The folder structure is something like below.

- Development

  - Dev1

    - A1.exe
    - conf1.config
  - Dev2

    - A1.exe
    - conf1.config
  - Dev3

    - A1.exe
    - conf1.config

The question is how can I auto merge those three dev branches to keep it synchronized with each other on every time someone check in a file to the branches? Do I need to look into PowerShell or does TFS supports something that can help?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you want to keep them synchronized, what is the point of having multiple branches? I don't understand your use case here.

Comment: completely agree with you @TToni. But unfortunately management doesn't agree with it, they want to keep it separate for some reason.

Comment: @Dinch Understanding their motivation is the first step to implementing a proper solution. The actual question is, "Why do we want to put these binaries in source control?" and going from there. Binaries shouldn't be in source control in the first place, so understanding what they're hoping to accomplish is critical.

Comment: @Daniel Mann, did you know worst thing about being software developer is having to implement something that you don't believe, but someone insists on the implementation, and they don't listen.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a script periodically that checks for new changesets and calls the respective merge commands. I like to use the [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics) from PowerShell through `Invoke-RestMethod` but not everything is covered there, so you may have to resort to the respective [TFS command line tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) or the [TFS .NET API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet).

If you want a nearly immediate check-in action, you will need to provide a server side plugin, similar to the one described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730333/tfs-2015-server-side-plugin-deployment-using-vs-2013).